# Navbar is not scrolling to sections on page anymore?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I added an li to my navbar and all of a sudden whenever I click the menu item, it doesn't scroll anymore. I need to make my navbar scroll to my section with Javascript.

Here is my navbar created with Javascript

```
const navMenu = document.querySelectorAll("section");
const navList = document.getElementById("navbar__list");
const items = ["Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3", "Section 4"];

//Build the nav
items.forEach((item, i) => {
  const el = document.createElement("a");
  el.innerText = item;
  el.classList.add("menu-items");
  el.setAttribute("id", `menu-${i + 1}`);
  el.href = `#section${i + 1}`;
  navList.appendChild(el);

  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.classList.add("menu-list");
  li.appendChild(el);

  // Append the list item to the list
  navList.appendChild(li);
});

//Make Nav Active when Clicked and scrolls down to section
document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  let active = document.querySelector(".menu-list.active");
  if (active) active.classList.remove("active");
  if (event.target.classList.contains("menu-list")) {
    event.target.classList.add("active");
  }
});
```

Before I only had the a tag added and I targeted .menu-items instead of .menu-list in the addEventListener, but once I added the li tag to my navbar, the class for li doesn't work. I'm not sure what to edit or change

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

idea of system is that give an id to menu item and using id to scrolling here u forgot to give id to element . I put it then in your click event get id and href to that section with using this id.

```
items.forEach((item, i) => {
  const el = document.createElement("a");
  el.innerText = item;
  el.classList.add("menu-items");
  el.setAttribute("id", `menu-${i + 1}`);
  el.href = `#section${i + 1}`;
  navList.appendChild(el);

  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.classList.add("menu-list");
  li.appendChild(el);
  li.setAttribute("id", `${i + 1}`);
  // Append the list item to the list
  navList.appendChild(li);
});

//Make Nav Active when Clicked and scrolls down to section
document.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  let active = document.querySelector(".menu-list.active");
  if (active) active.classList.remove("active");
  if (event.target.classList.contains("menu-list")) {
    event.target.classList.add("active");
    console.log(event.target.id);
    window.location.href="#section"+event.target.id
  }
});
```